# Class attribute inheritance when using properties in Python

Tags: python, class, inheritance, properties

I have the following code:

```
class Desc(object):
    @property
    def color_desc(self):
        return 'Color is ' + self.color

    @property
    def brand_desc(self):
        return 'Brand is ' + self.brand

class Text(Desc):
    def __init__(self):
        self.color = 'blue'
        self.brand = 'volvo'

def main():
    t = Text()
    print t.color_desc

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This correctly works and outputs `Color is blue` when run. However, if I modify the code slightly so that the property is set to an actual Class attribute, as in:

```
class Desc(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._color_desc = color_desc
        self._brand_desc = brand_desc

    @property
    def color_desc(self):
        return self._color_desc

    @color_desc.setter
    def color_desc(self):
        self._color_desc = 'Color is ' + self.color

    @property
    def brand_desc(self):
        return self._brand_desc

    @property
    def brand_desc(self):
        self._brand_desc = 'Brand is ' + self.brand


class Text(Desc):
    def __init__(self):
        self.color = 'blue'
        self.brand = 'volvo'
```

All of a sudden, it errs out with `AttributeError: 'Text' object has no attribute '_color_desc'`. How come the `Text` attributes are inherited correctly in the first place but cannot be accessed in the second one. To me, these two solutions seem to do the same thing.

Comment: just invoke base class's init method from child class's init method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call the `__init__` of the parent class.

Do something like this:

```
class Text(Desc):
    def __init__(self):
        self.color = 'blue'
        self.brand = 'volvo'
        super(Text, self).__init__(0,0)
```

The init function of your Desc class is incorrectly define. Do this:

```
class Desc(object):
    def __init__(self, color_desc, brand_desc):
        self._color_desc = color_desc
        self._brand_desc = brand_desc
```

Comment: `super(Text, self).__init__()` should be at the bottom.

Comment: I see, so the constructor is overridden. However, adding the `super` statement throws this error: `NameError: global name 'color_desc' is not defined`.

Comment: Because it isn't. What value is `Desc.__init__` supposed to use to set `self._color_desc`?

Comment: @chepner The value set by the setter of each property.

Comment: But you're not using the setter; you're assigning directly to the underlying attribute. The setter is only invoked if you assign *to* the name of the property.

Comment: Please note that I edited out `self.__class__` for a reason - I'm not sure where you heard it was a good idea, but see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/4235078/3001761 for why it's not.

Comment: I see, ok, I was not aware of that.

Answer (score 3):

In your `Text` class, the `__init__` is overriding the `Desc.__init__` class, so the `_color_desc` attributes is not initialized.

Answer (score -1):

It's not clear why you thought your second snippet would work at all. It has the following obvious issues:

- `Desc.__init__` is using two variables (`color_desc` and `brand_desc`) that aren't actually passed to it - are you expecting them to be in the global scope?
- You have two (different!) getters, one of which returns something, and no setter for `brand_desc`.
- The `color_desc` setter neither takes nor uses any parameter, so what exactly is it supposed to be setting?
- The subclass `Text.__init__` doesn't call or pass anything to the superclass version, or do the job itself.

I think what you intended was something like:

```
class Desc(object):

    def __init__(self, color_desc, brand_desc):
        self._color_desc = color_desc
        self._brand_desc = brand_desc

    @property
    def color_desc(self):
        return 'Color is ' + self._color_desc

    @color_desc.setter
    def color_desc(self, new_color):
        self._color_desc = new_color

    @property
    def brand_desc(self):
        return 'Brand is ' + self._brand_desc

    @brand_desc.setter
    def brand_desc(self, new_brand):
        self._brand_desc = new_brand    


class Text(Desc):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Text, self).__init__('blue', 'volvo')
```

Although now it looks like `Text` should be an *instance*, not a *subclass*, of `Desc`. You could also simplify by not assigning to e.g. `color_desc` at all, using a read-only property:

```
class Desc(object):

    def __init__(self, color, brand):
        self.color = color
        self.brand = brand

    @property
    def color_desc(self):
        return 'Color is ' + self.color

    @property
    def brand_desc(self):
        return 'Brand is ' + self.brand


car = Desc('blue', 'volvo')
car.color = 'red'
print car.color_desc  # Color is red
```

Now you set the instance's `.color` directly, but `.color_desc` still gives you the nicely-formatted version.

Comment: Yes, the intended code was as you said. I hurried the example code and missed a thing or two. Anyway, the simplified solution won't do since I specifically need a Car that has-a Description. The code was just an example and in reality the Description class should be reused for e.g. Boats, Trains, etc.

Comment: @mart1n if you need *"a Car that has-a Description"* then I think you're looking for **composition**, not **inheritance** (the latter would imply that a Car *is-a* Description, which doesn't seem right).