# Dynamic method resolution on a super() object

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to find a method on a `super()` object by name. This works when using the "dot operator" notation: `super(self.__class__,self).p`. However, I need to do that dynamically, something like `super(self.__class__,self)["p"]`, which does not work.

I tried to use `__getattr__`, but super object does not have that method. And `super(self.__class__,self).__getattribute__("p")` returns `self.p` instead `super().p`.

How to do that correctly and elegantly?

For instance:

```
class A(object):
    def p (self):
        skip

class B(object):
    def p (self):
        skip

class AB (A,B):
    def p (self):
        skip

ab = AB()
o = super(ab.__class__, ab)

print dir(o)
print o.__getattribute__("p").__code__
print o.p.__code__
```

This code outputs:

```
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__get__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__
', '__self__', '__self_class__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__thisclass__']
<code object p at 000000000205f2b0, file "b.py", line 10>  # AB.p
<code object p at 0000000000361cb0, file "b.py", line 2>   # A.p
```

Comment: ...what? Could you give a less abstract example of what you're trying to achieve? Also, passing `self.__class__` to `super` is a bad idea (see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/4235078/3001761).

Comment: @jonrsharpe He's not using self.__class__ inside the class. It will not cause any problem.

Comment: @Bharel actually we can't see whether or not they are, because of the oh-so-helpful `snip`. But it seems odd to use `ab.__class__` instead of `AB`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr). This works:

```
>>> getattr(o, "p")
<bound method A.p of <__main__.AB object at 0x0000000000AA8160>>
```

By using `__getattribute__()` directly, you lose the wrapping `super()` does to the object. You should always use `getattr()` for getting methods or other attributes. Generally, going directly to `__dunder__` methods is discouraged if there are other options.

Comment: Exactly, thanks a lot. I've spend a lot of time by figuring out how to do that, but without success.