# Concatenate class variable through inheritance?

Tags: python, inheritance

I am trying to **implicitly** concatenate class variables through inheritance. I was able to go up one level but not more... It this actually possible?

```
class Base(object):
    def get_crumbs(self):
        crumbs = getattr(super(self.__class__, self), 'crumbs', ())
        crumbs += getattr(self, 'crumbs', ())
        return crumbs


class A(Base):
    crumbs = ('un chasseur', )


class B(A):
    crumbs = ('sachant chasser', )


class C(B):
    crumbs = ('sans son chien', 'est un bon chasseur')


>>> c = C()
>>> c.get_crumbs()
>>> <type 'tuple'>: ('sachant chasser', 'sans son chien', 'est un bon chasseur')
```

Comment: Don't ever use `super(self.__class__, self)`; any subclassed method will now enter into infinite recursion. Either use the Python 3 version without arguments, or explicitly name the class. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235078/how-to-avoid-infinite-recursion-with-super

Comment: Since you're using class variables and tuples anyway, why not `class B(A): crumbs = A.crumbs + ('sachant chasser',)` and `class C(B): crumbs = B.crumbs + ('sans son chien', 'est un bon chasseur')`, and so on?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I thought of that, yes, but this is why I said **implicitly** :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop over the [`class.__mro__` tuple](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#class.__mro__):

```
class Base(object):
    def get_crumbs(self):
        crumbs = []
        for cls in type(self).__mro__:
            crumbs.extend(getattr(cls, 'crumbs', ()))
        return tuple(crumbs)
```

Demo:

```
>>> class Base(object):
...     def get_crumbs(self):
...         crumbs = []
...         for cls in type(self).__mro__:
...             crumbs.extend(getattr(cls, 'crumbs', ()))
...         return tuple(crumbs)
...
>>> class A(Base):
...     crumbs = ('un chasseur',)
...
>>> class B(A):
...     crumbs = ('sachant chasser',)
...
>>> class C(B):
...     crumbs = ('sans son chien', 'est un bon chasseur')
...
>>> c = C()
>>> c.get_crumbs()
('sans son chien', 'est un bon chasseur', 'sachant chasser', 'un chasseur')
```

Side note: don't use `super(self.__class__, self)`, ever. That'll lead to infinite recursion if you ever override the `get_crumbs()` method and use `super()` to call the original, see [How to avoid infinite recursion with super()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235078/how-to-avoid-infinite-recursion-with-super). Use `super(ClassName, self)` or (Python 3 only) `super()`, instead.

Comment: Okay that will do, except that the result is reversed (a simple `for cls in reversed(type(self).__mro__)` did the trick). Thank you!

Comment: @Pawamoy: ah, sorry, yes, it iterates in search order, so 'closest to the current class' comes first.